# What happens to the object parameters when you cast an object of type A to type B - Typescript

Tags: typescript, casting

I have a situation where I fetch data of Type ReadData.

```
interface ReadData {
  active: boolean,
  username: string,
  password: string
}
```

I then fill out the form and send the data back, but I first cast it to the type UpdateData since that is required by the backend.

```
interface UpdateData {
  username: string,
  password: string
}


sendDataToBackend(formData as UpdateData)
```

I always thought that when casting matching parameters are kept, parameters that are too much are deleted and missing parameters are filled with `null`.
I logged the `formData` before and after casting and noticed that `active` was still in there.

If I want to send a proper `formData` object of type `UpdateData` do I have to loop trough the object properties and delete them?
Something like this:

```
delete formData[key];
```